# Is there any way of determining which or statement is true in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So say I have an if statement:

```
if(a=='' || b==''){

    //which is true?
}
```

Is it possible  to determine which statement satisfied the if statement without doing a `switch` statement or another `if` statement to check?

Comment: `if (a) { ... } else if (b) { ... }` ?

Comment: try a ternary operator `var condition = a=='' ? 1 : 2;`

Comment: What's your goal?  There's usually a better way to do things if refactor the outer code.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand my goal is validating a form field.  So if telephone number & email is empty, show an error message below email.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand In fact just by explaining that, you have made me realise that its easier than I am making it out to be.  It's an and statement not an or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a token to store what condition was true:

```
var token = null;
if ((a == '' && (token = 'a')) || (b == '' && (token = 'b'))) {
    // Here token has an 'a' or a 'b'. You can use numbers instead of letters
}
```

I think it's the simplest way to do what you want.

Comment: how can you assign on a condition statement?

Comment: @rps, you can assign in any expression `alert(a=1);alert(a=a+1);alert(a=a+1)` (shows 1, then 2, then 3).  It just usually warrants a comment, because it's confusing.  Most people recommend against it, but I like it in situations like this answer (but not my alert example).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand [http://jsfiddle.net/H564A/](http://jsfiddle.net/H564A/) why the error then? can't see the value of the token

Comment: @rps, nice catch.  It looks like it would work, but I always wrap assignments in expressions, which is what needs to be done here.  [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MF2Jj/1/)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand it works! now, I will have to look into this _jsprint_ ( * _ * )

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you have to test the conditions separately, but you can kind of mix worlds.

```
var test1 = 1 == 1;  // true
var test2 = 2 == 1;  // false

if (test1 || test2) {
  // If either conditions is true, we end up here.
  // Do the common stuff
  if (test1) {
    // Handle test1 true
  }

  if (test2) {
    // Handle test2 true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have asked explicitly if one or both are true. There's no way to work out *which* of those sub-expressions is true without another conditional of some sort.

If you're interested in different behaviour based on which is true, you should probably separate them with a possibly-common bit, something like

```
either = false;
if (a == ' ') {
    doActionsForA();
    either = true;
}
if (b == ' ') {
    doActionsForB();
    either = true;
}
if (either) {
    doActionsForAorB();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about which of the two conditions is true the only way to find out is to test them separately, e.g.

```
if(a==''){
    // ...
}
else if(b=='') {
    // ...
}
```

Sometimes, especially in more complicated conditionals, it helps if you store the result of each condition and reuse it later on:

```
var isFoo = a == '';
var isBar = b == '';

// You can now use isFoo and isBar whenever it's convenient
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple solution:

```
if ((ia=(a=='')) || (b=='')) {
    // ia indicate whether the boolean expression a have been true.
    // ia -> a has been true, b may have, !ia -> b has been true, a has not
}
```

there is no `ib` in the simple solution as it won't be always be set due to shortcut evaluation.

to cater for shortcut evaluation try:

```
if (((ia=(a=='') || (ib=(b=='')) && ((ib=(b=='')) || (ia=(a==''))) {
    // ia, ib indicate whether the corresponding boolean expressions have been  true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>if(a=='' || b==''){
      var x= a || b;

       //if a is ''(falsy) x will be b, else a

    }</strike>

```
var phone="";
var email="something";

 if(phone=='' || email==''){

   var x= (phone) ? 'phone':'email';
   console.log(x); //email

}
```